# how to remove wikitude icon and splash screen in android?

Tags: android, wikitude

I am new to `Android AR development`. I want to use **WikitudeSDK** for development, but i am not able to **remove/replace** custom icon and **splash screen** provided by Wikitude? Anyone knows how to?

Comment: i am using it directly to my app, but the app is displaying splash screen showing wikitude's logo and wikitude logo in left bottom corner in AR view. Any chance to get rid of that?

Answer (score 1):

The Wikitude watermark will always be their until you purchase a license from Wikitude.

You can purchase a license from http://www.wikitude.com/store/buy-sdk?pcategory=buysdk